# TweetSharp doesn't post tweets with comma (%2C) in URL

Tags: .net, vb.net, tweets, tweetsharp

I posting tweets using `TweetSharp` (https://www.nuget.org/packages/TweetSharp/) in VB.NET console app:

```
msg = "TEST https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/devil+take+the+hindmost%2c+the"
service.SendTweet(New SendTweetOptions With {.Status = msg })
```

Everything works fine unless URL contains comma. In this case, nothing get posted (no error, just nothing happens). If I remove `%2c` from the example above, the tweet posts fine.

If I post the same tweet manually (from website twitter.com), everything works fine.

Comment: Does it fail if you replace %2 with a comma (pre-http encoded)?

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer. Indeed, if I don't encode the comma, it works. But why? And what about other punctuation marks (dots, semicolon, etc)? Spaces obviously need to be encoded anyway.

Comment: My guess is that TweetSharp does its own HTTP encoding.

Answer (score 0):

The problem solved. It turns out that if comma is not be encoded, all works:

```
msg = "TEST https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/devil+take+the+hindmost,+the"
service.SendTweet(New SendTweetOptions With {.Status = msg })
```

Still not sure if this is standard requirement or a bug of `TweetSharp`. And how I should treat other punctuation marks.